# Java Locale to country codes (ISO 3166)

Tags: java, locale, iso-3166

I have an instance of `Locale`, for example:

```java
Locale l = new Locale("en", "USA");
```

Now, I want to get the locale in the ISO 3166 format `en-US`. When I `toString` it though, I only get `en_USA` but not `en-US`.

How to do this correctly?

Comment: `Locale#toLanguageTag()` https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()

Comment: I don't think `USA` is a valid country/region code at all. In the link posted by Zabuzard, it is explicitly stated that this input is invalid: *"Country: If country is not well-formed (for example "12" or "USA"), it will be omitted."*

Comment: Yeah, the syntax for region has to be valid according to the ISO, see the constructor details and the javadoc of the whole class in general: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

### How to get the correct format?

First of all, the method to get the format you want is [Locale#toLanguageTag()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()), see this:

```java
System.out.println(Locale.US.toLanguageTag()); // en-US
```

---

### Why does USA not work?

Second, the region/country you provided in your constructor, `USA`, is **not** a valid region/country according to the ISO. The constructor hence simply ignored it. The correct region is `"US"`, then it also works:

```java
System.out.println(new Locale("en", "US").toLanguageTag()); // en-US
```

See the javadoc of the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

> country - An ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code or a UN M.49 numeric-3 area code. See the Locale class description about valid country values.

For details, refer to the excellent documentation of the class, it is very detailed.

---

### Valid codes

For a list of valid codes, refer to the ISO standard. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) also has a nice table:

[image: ISO language codes table]

and here is the entry for USA:

[image: usa entry]

Comment: Agree USA isn't a valid code but some place we use three letter code and my case it is three letter all the time. So we can't get USA to US

Comment: Well, that is a different question then though. And you should probably elaborate a bit, for example which standard you are following for the 3-letter thing. For example `GER` for `Germany`? What about `France`? `FRA`? And what about regions instead of just countries? Anyways, too much for this comment section. Id suggest you open a new question on SO instead, with all the details.